# ActiveSync Sync message not supporting all properties

Tags: activesync

I'm implementing an ActiveSync Java client. I can already communicate with the server and perform the protocol sequence to Sync emails, as defined in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee238029%28v=EXCHG.80%29.aspx).

However, when I try and send a `Sync` command it seems I can only use a subset of the available commands in the specification. When I use certain property tags in the Sync XML message I receive a Status 4 ('Protocol Error') code, even though these should be valid according to the specification.

When I use only the `GetChanges` property I do get a proper response, however I'd like to be able to specify how many items to return etc.

I've included the XML snippet that I'm sending: the commented out lines are lines that were attempted but caused a Status 4.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync:">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>{23423972324}</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>{23423sdfsdfsdfsf972324}</CollectionId>
            <GetChanges/>
            <!--<GetChanges>0</GetChanges>-->
            <!--<WindowSize>512</WindowSize>-->
            <!--<Options>-->
                <!--<Class>Email</Class>-->
                <!--<FilterType>3</FilterType>-->
                <!--<MaxItems>10</MaxItems>-->
            <!--</Options>-->
            <!--<Commands>-->
            <!--    <Fetch>-->
            <!--        <ServerId>1:323</ServerId>-->
            <!--    </Fetch>-->
            <!--</Commands>-->
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
    <!--<WindowSize>512</WindowSize>-->
</Sync>
```

Is there any reason why these properties shouldn't be supported? Or is there something I've left out of the message?

The `GetOptions` command for the server returns the following (truncated):

```
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0,
    X-Powered-By: ASP.NET,
    Pragma: no-cache,
    Public: OPTIONS, POST, Allow: OPTIONS, POST,
    MS-Server-ActiveSync: 6.5.7653.19,
    MS-ASProtocolVersions: 1.0,2.0,2.1,2.5,
    MS-ASProtocolCommands:Sync,SendMail,SmartForward,SmartReply,GetAttachment,GetHierarchy,CreateCollection,DeleteCollection,MoveCollection,FolderSync,FolderCreate,FolderDelete,FolderUpdate,MoveItems,GetItemEstimate,MeetingResponse,ResolveRecipients,ValidateCert,Provision,Search,Notify,Ping
```

Comment: UPDATE: I've been able to use a Proxy to catch the messages being passed from the Android Emulator Email client and it seems that it IS able to successfully use the properties that don't work in my Java Client. I've tried to replicate exactly the HTTP messages sent from Android in my Java client but I always get a status 4 message from Exchange.

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the WBXML encode/decoder I was using wasn't working correctly. I figured this out by comparing the byte code generated by two different WBXML encoders and saw a difference. The encoder I was using didn't process empty elements like  properly. I fixed it and now the server acts as expected.